# Array Sorting according to two or more values

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How can i accomplish sorting an array according to two values. 
Is there built in function for that?

Comment: found it, so quick->   sortArray.sortOn(['d_year', 'd_month'], Array.NUMERIC);

Comment: You are able to post an answer on your own question and accept it - just letting you know.

Comment: what should i do, i did not stop searching after asking.

Comment: Ah I just mean that for the sake of other people browsing for answers to the same question; you should answer your own question and mark it as correct so when people see this page they'll see the answer :)

Comment: oki i got it, but site is very detailed. i dont know how to mark yet. i cant mark my own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**

In my loop I insert values into my array like so:

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i++)
{
    sortArray[i].year = xmlList[i].year;
    sortArray[i].month = xmlList[i].month;
}
```

And to **sort** this array: (edited)

```
sortArray.sortOn(['year', 'month'], [Array.NUMERIC, Array.NUMERIC]);
```

Comment: Now if you press the outline of a tick to the left this will be marked as the answer you were after.

Comment: I don't recomend to use `i < xmlList.length()` in loop. If you put something that may change while doing code into the loop it will be calculated each time. So, to increase performance declare `var n = xmlList.length()`, and then `for(var i:uint = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: i know that, try this one->  var i=0; for(; i < n; ++i)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [sortOn()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29) function.

Comment: that is the place i found my answer. i wrote it already. thanks anyway.

Comment: @viaria - this IS the correct answer, if you are missing things, please tell us what.

Comment: i already knew that built in function, what i didnt know is how to use it. i wrote a sample down here.